# Google conversions not registering within PHP page

Tags: php, analytics, tracking, google-ads-api, goal-tracking

Although relatively new to coding, I have successfully implemented a number of tracking codes before, but I am having serious problems getting one conversion code to register on my site.

Whilst I have put it into the relevant section of PHP in the code, and even done test conversions and seen it in the source, Google has failed to register a single conversion and the goal still shows up as 'Unverified'.

I have read various blogs and what Google has to say about implementing the code in PHP - most of which seem to disagree with one another. If anyone has any ideas, I would be hugely grateful as it is a key indicator to tracking my AdWords performance.

Below is the code that Google gives me to implement untouched:

```
<!-- Google Code for Almost there Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 974608389;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "d5KfCMunhgUQhbDd0AM";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/974608389/?value=0&amp;label=d5KfCMunhgUQhbDd0AM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Now the code the way Google wants you to edit it for PHP, detailed under the section here: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722054?hl=en-GB

```
<!-- Google Code for Almost there Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 974608389;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "d5KfCMunhgUQhbDd0AM";
if (<%= totalValue %) {
    var google_conversion_value = <%= totalValue %>;
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/974608389/?value=0&amp;label=d5KfCMunhgUQhbDd0AM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

I have wasted about 3 days on this on and off now and have spent long enough trying to click on adverts and creating fake accounts to test it with to get it to trigger.

**As another safeguard I will post the relevant PHP section in it's entirety below too.**

It's a part triggered to confirm a subscription payment may be useful to see you can never have too much information, diagnosing a problem.

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Subscription Confirmation */

  if (isset($_POST['activate_subscription']) && isset($_POST['token'])) {
    $activation = completeSubscription($_POST['token']);
    //completeSubscription Handles everything here. If this even runs, it's all gone wrong.
    $activate_failed = true;
  } else if (isset($_GET['token']) && isset($_GET['PayerID'])) {
    $transaction = getTransactionDetails($_GET['token']);
    if ($transaction['ACK'] == "Success") $sub = updateSubscriptionDetails($transaction);
  } else {
    header("Location: /join/membership/");
    exit();
  }



  get_header();
?>

<div class="row subhero">
  <div class="twelve columns">

    <?php if (!isset($activate_failed) && $transaction['ACK'] == "Success") { ?>

      <h1>Almost there!</h1>
      <p class="subheader">Thank you for configuring your subscription with PayPal.</p>
//***************** ANALYTICS CODE
<!-- Google Code for Subscription Conf Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 974608389;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "d5KfCMunhgUQhbDd0AM";
if (<%= totalValue %) {
    var google_conversion_value = <%= totalValue %>;
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/974608389/?value=0&amp;label=d5KfCMunhgUQhbDd0AM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
//*********************END OF ANALYTICS CODE
  </div>
  </div>      
</div> <!-- end container -->
<div class="buyticketarea">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="eight columns offset-by-two">       


      <p class="subheader">Please confirm the following details. Once you proceed you will be billed immediately for your first month of <strong><?php echo $transaction['L_NAME0']; ?></strong> at <strong>&pound;<?php echo $transaction['L_AMT0']; ?>.</strong></p>
      <p class="subheader">Additionally, you will be billed <strong>&pound;<?php echo $transaction['L_AMT0']; ?></strong> on the <strong><?php echo date('j'); ?><sup><?php echo date('S'); ?></sup></strong> of each month, starting on <strong><?php echo getNextBillingDayHuman(); ?>.</strong></p>
      <p class="subheader">If you're happy to proceed...</p>
      <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="sub_id" value="<?php echo $transaction['INVNUM']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_GET['token']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="PayerID" value="<?php echo $_GET['PayerID']; ?>" />
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="activate_subscription" value="Activate Subscription" />
      </form>

    </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line looks wrong to me:

```
if (<%= totalValue %) {
    var google_conversion_value = <%= totalValue %>;
}
```

Looking at other examples it should be:

```
if (<?php echo $totalValue ?>) {
    var google_conversion_value = <?php echo totalValue ?>;
}
```

But, you aren't setting the value for `$totalValue` so maybe all conversions have equal value? In which case you should just use:

```
var google_conversion_value = 10;
```